# How to create .mdf file from .sql file in visual studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2015

I have a sql script (a complete database). I want import it to a Microsoft SQL Server database (`.mdf` file)

How to can do that ?

Comment: You need to **(1)** create the SQL Server database file, **(2)** execute the `.sql` script on that newly created database file to have it create all the database objects (and possibly fill in some static data)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828060/how-do-i-import-a-sql-data-file-into-sql-server