# Execute .SQL file with VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sql-scripts, vba7

I would like to know if there is any VBA code which allows me to execute `.sql` files by clicking a button in Excel?

I've been surfing different webs, but all of them showed code which consists into write the SQL query in the macro, despite it isn't what I wanted. So I have stored `.sql` scripts as files in different folders on my computer and what I want is to run this script by clicking a button in Excel using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. There is no magic button in Excel that does that. Easiest that I can think of is run/import that .sql to MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc. to become a database. Example using MS SQL Server:

[How do I import a .sql data file into SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828060/how-do-i-import-a-sql-data-file-into-sql-server)

Once you run successfully that .sql into a DBMS, you may use built-in tools of that DBMS to export the tables into Excel. See the link below as an example:

[How to Import and Export SQL Server data to an Excel file](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/)

It may not be as easy as pressing a button but not as tedious as hardcoding it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer! Indeed, I have created these scripts in SQL Server and as I have to execute some codes in VBA which update this databases. I wanted to find this code to open those .sql files and run them. I know you have for instance the VBA code "Do.Cmd.OpenQuery" to open Access db and run any query save in this Access db.